# python Error:Exception in thread Thread-18:

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

following Error occure in myscript.my system anaconda folder threading.py file exist but error line 810 does not exist.plz suggest proper solution

```
Exception in thread Thread-18:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\envoy\core.py", line 32, in target
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 957, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

followind code error occure
        AttributeError   Traceback (most recent call last)
         in ()

```
    8 F='resources/ch06-mailboxes/data/enron.mbox.json.bz2'
    9 r = envoy.run("bunzip2 %s" % (F,)) --->this line error occured
    10 print r.std_out
    11 print r.std_err

   C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\envoy\core.py in run(command, data, timeout)
   166 
   167         cmd = Command(c)
   168         out, err = cmd.run(data, timeout)  --->this line error occured
   169 
   170         r = Response(process=cmd)

   C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\envoy\core.py in run(self, data, timeout)
   51             self.process=process;
   52             thread.join()
   53         self.returncode = self.process.returncode ---->this line error occured
   54         return self.out, self.err
   55 

   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'returncode'
```

Answer (score 0):

The message as such is fairly self-explanatory: "The system cannot find the file specified". I would recommend you do verify you provided the correct directory route to the script.

It would be good also for you to provide more context on the error per se. Is error the thread longer?, can you show the original code creating the error?